# Same CIGaussianBlur effect archives two highly different results depending on the background

Tags: swift, image, cifilter

I am trying to achieve a the same gaussian blur as Photoshop does but it's seems the CIFilter in Core Image is very biased on the background of the image. I am not talking about the blurred edges, please look closer at the blue intensity between white and dark background of the CIFilter blurred version and Photoshop.

Input images:

[image]

[image]

Core Image result:

[image]
[image]

Photoshop result:

[image]
[image]

You can clearly see CIGaussianBlur outputs a very different image.

This is the code used to generate the images on iOS:

```swift
let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "1", withExtension: "png")!
let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL)!
let extent = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: ciImage.extent.size)
let blurredImage = CIFilter.gaussianBlur()
blurredImage.radius = 64
blurredImage.inputImage = ciImage

let outputURL = try! FileService.shared.getNewFileURL(type: "jpeg")
let context = CIContext()
try! context.writeJPEGRepresentation(of: blurredImage.outputImage!.cropped(to: extent), to: outputURL, colorSpace: colorSpace)
```

Comment: But to your question: my feeling is that CIFilter _is_ doing it correctly, while photoshop is applying some magic: gaussian blur works the best on image with "normal" contrast, while your second image is high contrast, so naturally "higher-middle-pixels" blend into more light than their initial colors. Question is: why it's a problem (maybe it's not). And if it is, you could for example reduce contrast of the image before applying GB, or you could experiment on  ccontrast-dependent `radius`...

Comment: It's a huge issue for me as I am using this filter to generate a drop shadow effect and it's very inconvenient to generate different results based on the background

Comment: The only other idea I have is to try using Accelerate instead of CI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/blurring_an_image.

Comment: I guess Photoshop applies the blur with a perceptual (sRGB) gamma curve, while Core Image uses linear by default. Can you please try to call `ciImage.applyingFilter("CILinearToSRGBToneCurve")` on the input before passing it to the blur and `output.applyingFilter("CISRGBToneCurveToLinear")` on the output and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you a lot. You can add this comment as an answer as it is correct. Thank you a lot!